# How to programatically set and unset/remove print area in Google sheet using app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have a table that has a fixed number of columns and a dynamic number of data rows. I would like to set and unset the print area until the getLastRow() of the sheet.

```
Columns: 7 (fixed)
Rows:    getLastRow() (nth row is dynamic and depends on query result)
```

I've been looking for code solutions but can't find one.

Code should behave like this:

```
set printarea with print_area_name and range of A1:G&getLastRow()
functions()...
unset or remove printarea with print_area_name
```

Last row pic (row 67 is the lastrow):

[image]

When the script runs to create the print area, we should see it created from this pic below...

Print area is normally created like this, but how can we automate the range of the print area using the range in the data table?

[image]

And how to delete this print area by triggering the script?

Comment: Please provide the sample input and desired output in images.

Comment: PLs see pics if that suffices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are trying to say 'named range'.

- Get: [getRangeByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangebynamename)
- Update: [setRange(range)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range#setrangerange)
- Remove: [remove()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range#remove)

Comment: thank you! im still a little bit new to the library.